# How to bind checkboxes to nullable byte fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Input tag helpers require checkboxes to be bound to non-nullable boolean fields yet my legacy sql tables contain nullable tinyint fields. Existing data is 1, 0 or Null. Entity Framework generates nullable `byte?` properties for those fields in the model. My razor page is bound directly to the generated database model. Now I want to bind checkboxes to those fields. What options are available? Changing the database is not possible.

Should I make matching bound boolean properties in the razor page model? In the get/set I could pull/push converted values to the database model's `byte?` fields. In the past (using non-razor MVC) I've bound my page to a viewmodel with the generated model hanging off of it in a property. That allowed me to bind to the viewmodel and "fix" data issues in the controller.

I'll try that idea but I'm wondering if I'm heading down the wrong path?

EDIT: I found a solution which I'll post as an answer. My original idea (above) failed (coding in property get/set) because the database model was null at that time. Instead I pull/push values in the OnGet and OnPost routines. Still I'm not sure if the is the preferred way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a nullable byte field named OnChart in the database model:

```
 public byte? OnChart { get; set; }
```

Create a corresponding bound boolean field in the page model:

```
 [BindProperty]
 public bool OnChartBoolean { get; set; }
```

In the razor page bind to the bool property:

```
<input asp-for="OnChartBoolean" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" >
```

You can then convert and move the data from the `byte?` field to the `bool` (and back) in the OnGet and OnPost routines. In the OnGet routine:

```
        if (myTable.OnChart == null || myTable.OnChart == 0)
        {
            OnChartBoolean = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            OnChartBoolean = true;
        }
```

Then in the OnPost routine:

```
    if (OnChartBoolean == false)
    {
        myTable.OnChart = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        myTable.OnChart = 1;
    }
```